# Athena querying fails while calling Glue virtual view with invalid JSON error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am trying to create an Glue virtual view (table_type = "VIRTUAL_VIEW"), through which I can query through Athena. I am doing this through Terraform. I am able to successfully create the Glue view using below Terraform code, but then it fails as below error (INVALID_VIEW: Invalid view JSON: SELECT id, module, projectid FROM test_data."test_metrics" limit 10). I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, I guess it is it something to do with the way I am passing query to the VIEW, but tried few ways, but in vain. Any help would gretaly be appreciated :). Thank you.

```
locals {
  database      = "test_data"
  query   = "SELECT id, \nmodule, \nprojectid FROM ${local.database}.\"test_metrics\"  limit 10"
}

resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "story_view" {

  database_name = local.database
  name = "story_flow_details"

  table_type = "VIRTUAL_VIEW"
  view_original_text = "/* Presto View: ${base64encode(local.query)} */"
  view_expanded_text = "/* Presto View */"

  parameters = {
    presto_view = "true"
    comment = "Presto View"
  }

  storage_descriptor {
    ser_de_info {
      name = "JsonHiveSerDe1"
      serialization_library = "org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe"
    }

     columns {
      name = "id"
      type = "string"
    }

    columns {
      name = "module"
      type = "string"
    }

    columns {
      name    = "projectid"
      type    = "string"
      comment = ""
    }
}
}
```

**Your query has the following error(s):
INVALID_VIEW: Invalid view JSON: SELECT id, module, projectid FROM test_data."test_metrics" limit 10;
This query ran against the "test_data" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: 79231ddc-d77c-4660-bf70-b84009a82082.**

Comment: Also when I see the view query now, it just has the syntax CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW sub_task_flow_details AS 
But does not actually have the query inside it. But when I create a view manually though, I am able to see the actual query.